# PySide2 QAction Event Blocked until window closed

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyside2

Ran into an issue that seems like the event loop is blocked (or I didn't start one?) and I haven't been able to chase it down.

The GUI comes up, and the menus are responsive, but clicking File->Open, which *should* create an near immediate print statement doesn't happen.

I know I have the correct signal mapped to the slot because as soon as you do a File->Quit or close the window, the print statement comes out.

I implemented this same example in C++ with the identical UI file and it works as expected.

Problem exhibits in the following configurations:

- Windows 10, Python 3.6.4, pyside2-5.11.1a1.dev1530708810518
- Windows 10, Python 2.7.14, pyside2-5.11.0a1.dev1528378291

**test.ui:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>200</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Qt for Python</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>940</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionOpen"/>
    <addaction name="actionQuit"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
  </widget>
  <action name="actionQuit">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Quit</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionOpen">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Open</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>actionQuit</sender>
   <signal>triggered()</signal>
   <receiver>MainWindow</receiver>
   <slot>close()</slot>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

**test.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile


class MyWidget(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

        file = QFile("test.ui")
        file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)

        loader = QUiLoader()
        self.ui = loader.load(file)

        openAction = self.ui.findChild(QtWidgets.QAction, 'actionOpen')
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.func)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def func(self):
        print("func has been called!")

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
myWidget = MyWidget()
myWidget.ui.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It works for me correctly, I'm using PySide2 5.11 on Linux

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc I ran this under Linux and it worked as expected, I'm going to open a bug with Qt if there isn't one already.  Thanks for verifying my sanity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with PySide2 on Windows, opened bug [PYSIDE-767](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-767)